# What is the usage of checked exceptions in java?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

In oracle doc it says

> If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

For example, ClassNotFoundException and CloneNotSupportedException are two examples of checked exceptions, but if we catch these types of exception in runtime, the client can't do anything to resolve them.
But if they mean developer by the word client, it doesn't make sense either because programmer can't do anything at runtime to recover from these types of exceptions.

Comment: Yes, he can. On CloneNotSupportedException he can resort to another copying algorithm. On ClassNotFoundException he could try to find another Class to instantiate (think about reflection).

Comment: Based on your analogy , you can tell the same thing for uncheck exceptions, for example in case of ArithmeticException or IllegalArgumentException you can ask user for new (correct) values.

Comment: That's correct. But changing the algorithm for cloning can be done **without** user interaction. When you encounter an Illegal Argument you cannot recover **without** more info.

Comment: So you are inferring the word `reasonably`  in oracle doc , means silently and without user interaction. Cause I think asking for correct input from user is reasonable enough.

Comment: Yes because "client" is meant as "code that calls the method that throws the exception".

Comment: Personally I think java founders, divided exceptions into two groups (check and unchecked), because for one group (unchecked exceptions), there were lots of reasons to happen, so if you had to handle them, you would be forced to flood your code with try/catch blocks ( think about null pointer exception) . on the other hand there were checked exceptions that could happen rarely , so for these cases you need to handle them.

Comment: Good point  for your def of client

Answer (score 1):

Two things on top of my  mind

1. To clear the mess when something goes wrong / continue as if nothing happened / try an alternate way of doing the task. Say you have opened a database connection and reading from it. If some exception is thrown you want to make sure you clean up the mess before you leave the place. For example, you may use connection.close() in the finally block among other things. You don't want your application to fatally throw an exception for a not so serious error.
2. **You might want to re throw the exception**. Say it is the same exception as above, but that is not message you want to show your user. You may write a mapper that throws a custom exception you have written with the message you want.